# How to make mysqldump work well for a WordPress database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bash

I am trying to automate the export of a WordPress database. Below is the format of the command and the output (an unexpected error). If you try this on your computer, please replace the tokens `my-mysql-user`, `my-mysql-password`, `my-mysql-server.com` and `my-wp-database` with your own data.

```sh
$ mysqldump -u"my-mysql-user" -p"my-mysql-password" -h"my-mysql-server.com" "my-wp-database" -r sql-dumps/dump.sql
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,                       JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"')                FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS                WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'my-wp-database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'wp_commentmeta';': Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)
```

The output in the dump.sql file is incomplete:

```sql
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.19, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: my-mysql-server.com    Database: my-wp-database
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.5-10.3.22-MariaDB-cll-lve

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_commentmeta`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_commentmeta`
--

LOCK TABLES `wp_commentmeta` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_commentmeta` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_commentmeta` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

More information:

```sh
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Is it possible that the problem is caused by the difference between versions of the MySQL server and the client?

Having the above error output, what can I do to make the `mysqldump` command work well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very successfully back up wordpress databases with:

```
export MYSQL_PWD=[password]
mysqldump -u [user] --routines --triggers --add-locks --disable-keys --single-transaction [databasename]
```

Passing the password as an environment variable means that it doesn't appear in the process list. For Wordpress, you probably don't need `--routines --triggers`, unless you've got some sophisticated plugins that use triggers or custom functions.

It looks to me, though, that your error is most likely related to this line:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, 
JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"') FROM 
.COLUMN_STATISTICS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'my-wp-database' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'wp_commentmeta';': 
Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)
```

My guess would indeed be that this is an incompatibility between your MySQL server (v5.5) and your mysqldump (v10.13). Can you find a v5.x of mysqldump to try?

Comment: No, I cannot find a `v5.x` of `mysqldump` to try. I have searched the default Ubuntu package repositories and I have tried every method in this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/. It seems to me that the only way is to build from source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/source-installation.html with https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/5.7.

Comment: Everything works well if I use `mysqldump` from a mysql Docker container that I already had in use. Thank you!